# PHP two while loops taking turns

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I want to make an output with two while loops in PHP where both while loops take turns by returning values like if they are 'taking turns'...

For example:
While loop1 echoes A1, A2, A3 etc
While loop2 echoes B1, B2, B3 etc

I want my output to be like this:

A1
B1
A2
B2
A3
B3
etc etc

Anyone has any ideas on how to do this? I want to implement this idea in a bar-graph kind of overview. I want to compare every week of two years' data. The bar graph is done with using a While Loop. It's a horizontal bar graph (the bars 'lay down') and I want to make it like this:

Week 1 of year x
Week 1 of year x-1
Week 2 of year x
Week 2 of year x-1
Week 3 of year x
Week 3 of year x-1

etc

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are these values in an array, or you just creating them as the loop runs?

Answer (score 5):

If the values come from two different arrays, you can iterate through them together using a MultipleIterator

```
$firstArray = array('A1','A2','A3');
$secondArray = array('B1','B2','B3');

$mi = new MultipleIterator();
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($firstArray));
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($secondArray));

foreach ( $mi as $value ) {
    list($first, $second) = $value;
    echo $first , PHP_EOL , $second , PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: +1 Nice use of the iterator. Far superior to what I was going to post.

Comment: @Leigh - SPL is like the undiscovered country of PHP

Comment: Hello Mark Baker, thank you for your answer. But I want to build both bar graphs out of MySql data. I'm very sorry I forgot to mention that. But the A1, B1 etc is what I am taking from my database.. I have to use a normal While or For loop here I guess?

Comment: Then show use your db query, and what you're getting from that; you might be able to order the returned resultset differently, or possibly to array_chunk to split your resultset into two parts

Comment: The result I get from my while loop is (in a html table) all the data from my table. For example, if I search on year 2012, I get all the values where year=2012... Now I want to create a new table with 2012, then 2011, then 2012 again, and then 2011 again... Taking turns with the data echo'ed in a table